# What is the mechanism behind of optical mode combination in waveguide?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics, waveguide

In mode combiner (in waveguide) modes of different phases or the same phase get combined and turn into a new mode. Here is a picture of mode combination process of a mode generator from a paper.

paper link: (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1704875)

[image: mode split and combination in output]

My main confusion is in the middle two arms modes which are 180degree out of phase which get combined and didn't vanish but turned into another mode.For ease of understanding I have drawn the middle part of 1st figure in this 2nd figure

[image: combination of different mode out of phase]

I couldn't find any logic behind this kind of combination.

Answer (score 0):

This scheme is an idea analogous to having a pair of parallel plate metal guides side by side each in their fundamental mode but out of phase (each transversal mode has a distribution a half cycle) and then we combine them in a single *double* height parallel plate guide mode so that the latter has now a transversal distribution such that is a full cycle.

Here they use four guides and by fine adjustments between the phases the amplitude distribution in the transversal plane is controlled.

In the case of metal guides the design complication is to make sure that there is minimal reflection at the junction; this can be done by introducing various tuning screws, septums, etc., here the junction shape is available for that purpose and external phase shifts are by heating elements.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your point. ''we combine them in a single double height parallel plate guide mode so that the latter has now a transversal distribution such that is a full cycle''. Can you tell me in simple the mechanism behind the combination?? And the analogy you have given, I don't know about it.

Comment: are you familiar with a parallel plate guide and its modes and do you know what a T-junction is and how it works?

Comment: little knowledge on parallel plate guide only. Does it need to know some large quantity of basics on those topic?? I mean , any short simple answer or link to  understand only that combination technique available?